Adding Year and Month Columns to a ts Object
I have a data frame of daily time seriws climate data in CSV format. The data frame has four columns of date,Prec,Tmax and Tmin. The CSV file can be downloaded Here. I want to convert the data frame into a monthly ts object with the five colums of Year, Month, Prec,Tmax and Tmin.
I have created the following code to convert the data:
#Load Required packages
library(xts)

#Loading Data
df <- read.csv("ClimData.csv")

#Create Rdate format
date <- as.Date(df$date, format = '%m/%d/%Y')

#Convert tada to an xts Objects

prec <- xts(df$Prec, date)
tmin <-xts(df$Tmin, date)
tmax <-xts(df$Tmax, date)

#Convert to Monthly Values

prec_m <- apply.monthly(prec, sum)
tmin_m <- apply.monthly(tmin, mean)
tmax_m <- apply.monthly(tmax, mean)

#Create Data frames

d_prec <- as.data.frame(prec_m)
d_tmin <- as.data.frame(tmin_m)
d_tmax <- as.data.frame(tmax_m)

#Combine the data frames
dt <- cbind.data.frame(d_prec, d_tmin, d_tmax)
colnames(dt) <- c('Prec', 'Tmin', 'Tmax')

#Convert to a Time series objects
dt <- ts(dt[c(1:3)], start = c(2020, 1), end = c(2023, 12), frequency = 12)
View(dt)

plot.ts(dt)

The results I'm getting is as follows
> dt
          Prec     Tmin     Tmax
Jan 2020 209.2 17.78248 28.12348
Feb 2020 194.4 17.15297 29.27645
Mar 2020 313.9 16.96681 28.96835
Apr 2020 219.3 16.51617 28.64863
May 2020   0.0 14.40332 29.21816
Jun 2020   0.0 13.86453 28.98593
Jul 2020   0.0 13.91129 28.75810
Aug 2020   0.0 15.35545 30.56526
Sep 2020   0.0 16.52877 31.66443
Oct 2020  17.1 17.34668 30.20081
Nov 2020 170.7 16.71463 29.17023
Dec 2020 130.0 17.08645 28.77268
Jan 2021 175.0 17.35477 26.90087
Feb 2021 448.7 17.22093 29.13764

I want the resulits tobe like the following
> dt
    Month Year Prec Tmin   Tmax
Jan 2020 209.2 17.78248 28.12348
Feb 2020 194.4 17.15297 29.27645
Mar 2020 313.9 16.96681 28.96835
Apr 2020 219.3 16.51617 28.64863
May 2020   0.0 14.40332 29.21816
Jun 2020   0.0 13.86453 28.98593
Jul 2020   0.0 13.91129 28.75810
Aug 2020   0.0 15.35545 30.56526
Sep 2020   0.0 16.52877 31.66443
Oct 2020  17.1 17.34668 30.20081
Nov 2020 170.7 16.71463 29.17023
Dec 2020 130.0 17.08645 28.77268
Jan 2021 175.0 17.35477 26.90087
Feb 2021 448.7 17.22093 29.13764


Read the file using read.csv.zoo and separately aggregate each column.  Then cbind the Month and Year and convert to ts class.
library(zoo)

z <- read.csv.zoo("ClimData.csv", format = "%m/%d/%Y")
zz <- cbind(Prec = aggregate(z$Prec, as.yearmon, sum),
            Tmin = aggregate(z$Tmin, as.yearmon, mean),
            Tmax = aggregate(z$Tmax, as.yearmon, mean))
tt <- with(zz, 
    cbind(Month = cycle(zz), Year = as.integer(time(zz)), Prec, Tmin, Tmax)) |>
  as.ts()

tt

##          Month Year  Prec     Tmin     Tmax
## Jan 2020     1 2020 209.2 17.78248 28.12348
## Feb 2020     2 2020 194.4 17.15297 29.27645
## Mar 2020     3 2020 313.9 16.96681 28.96835
## Apr 2020     4 2020 219.3 16.51617 28.64863
## May 2020     5 2020   0.0 14.40332 29.21816
## ... snip ...

or write it as a single pipeline like this:
"ClimData.csv" |>
  read.csv.zoo(format = "%m/%d/%Y") |>
  with(cbind(Prec = aggregate(Prec, as.yearmon, sum),
            Tmin = aggregate(Tmin, as.yearmon, mean),
            Tmax = aggregate(Tmax, as.yearmon, mean))) |>
  with(cbind(Month = cycle(Prec), Year = as.integer(time(Prec)), 
             Prec, Tmin, Tmax)) |>
  as.ts()

